# Apply same SQL SELECT query to different columns

Tags: select, sqlite

If this question turns out to be very basic, I will delete it. I have an SQLite table with the following schema:

```
sqlite> .schema complexity
CREATE TABLE complexity (
  plan_id TEXT NOT NULL,
  arc INTEGER NOT NULL,
  coa REAL,
  em REAL,
  efs REAL,
  ltmean REAL,
  mcs REAL,
  mcsv REAL,
  mfa REAL,
  pi REAL,
  sas REAL,
  FOREIGN KEY (plan_id) REFERENCES plan (plan_id)
);
CREATE INDEX complexityindex ON complexity(plan_id);
```

And this is my table's contents:

```
plan_id arc coa     em      efs     ltmean  mcs     mcsv    mfa         pi      sas
112-19  1   0.317   0.26    57.631  0.561   0.212   0.212   6781.489    52.764  0.139
112-19  2   0.361   0.277   52.712  0.576   0.16    0.16    4991.226    48.033  0.167
443-18  1   0.334   0.25    76.283  0.407   0.175   0.175   7656.262    61.616  0.124
443-18  2   0.315   0.243   79.174  0.416   0.195   0.194   8130.702    61.332  0.098
231-18  1   0.326   0.264   53.622  0.602   0.216   0.215   6015.724    48.917  0.137
231-18  2   0.334   0.265   52.175  0.609   0.196   0.195   5288.368    45.981  0.144
236-20  1   0.368   0.271   27.209  0.775   0.229   0.228   2263.918    23.056  0.212
```

Given a plan with id plan_id, I'd like to calculate the percentile of that plan for the columns coa, em, efs, ..., sas. I've come up with the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT plan_id, coa, PERCENT_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY coa)
        FROM complexity
    )
    WHERE plan_id = "112-19";
```

And I get:

```
plan_id coa     PERCENT_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY coa)
112-19  0.317   0.166666666666667
112-19  0.361   0.833333333333333
```

How could I calculate the percent rank order by the rest of the columns, without copy/pasting the above SQL query and replacing 'coa' with 'efs', then 'em', etc.?

Comment: What would the desired output look like? I don't think you can avoid calculating percentile along each column, and to do that you _have_ to tell the database to calculate it for each column.

Comment: Without copy-paste? only while type by hands... Of course you may build the query which will convert your data to EAV, calculate precentiles while partitioning by attribute then pivot back - but the query will be too complex.

Comment: You could unpivot maybe, depends what you are trying to get